# How to remove index in Titan DB (berkeleyJE backend) using gremlin?

Tags: graph, titan, gremlin, tinkerpop, berkeley-db-je

I am unable to remove an index from a Titan DB, with berkeleyJE backend.

The status of the index never changes from INSTALLED to DISABLED.

I have tried with both a Java program and with gremlin commands.

See the gremlin commands I have used below, and the negative result in the response the last command.

Any idea what is going wrong?

Thanks,
Matthew

```
     \,,,/
         (o o)
-----oOOo-(3)-oOOo-----
gremlin> graph = TitanFactory.open('../conf/titan-berkeleyje.properties')
==>standardtitangraph[berkeleyje:/TCB/BalanceReporter/db]

gremlin> mgmt = graph.openManagement()
==>com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.management.ManagementSystem@2b289ac9

gremlin> property = mgmt.getPropertyKey('account.reference')
==>account.reference

gremlin> index = mgmt.getGraphIndex('account.reference')
==>account.reference

gremlin> indexStatus = index.getIndexStatus(property)
==>INSTALLED

gremlin> mgmt.updateIndex(index, SchemaAction.DISABLE_INDEX)
==>com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.management.ManagementSystem$EmptyIndexJobFuture@7bc44ce8

gremlin> mgmt.commit()
==>null

gremlin> if (graph.getOpenTransactions()) graph.tx().rollback()
==>null

gremlin> mgmt.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, 'account.reference').status(SchemaStatus.DISABLED).call()
==>GraphIndexStatusReport[success=false, indexName='account.reference', targetStatus=DISABLED, notConverged={account.reference=INSTALLED}, converged={}, elapsed=PT1M0.155S]
```

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this issue? Please share your findings.

Comment: A made a workaround. I built a tool in java to create a new graph DB with the new schema and to copy all vertices and edges from old DB to new.

Comment: That sounds interesting. It seems like you basically migrated the data from first DB store to second DB store, behind the scenes, where the second DB store had new index. Sounds like a very good apporach :-) I hope this would be supported by TinkerPop out-of-the-box someday.